# Resizeable image with scaling overlays in JSF

Tags: image, jsf, overlay, resizable, primefaces-extensions

I would like to draw an image with JSF (primefaces) and draw some overlays (rectangles) on the image. The image should be resizable but must keep the image ratio and the overlay should scale also.

I tried:

```
<pe:layout id="fullPage" options="#{myManagedBean.layoutOptions}" fullPage="true" widgetVar="fpLayoutWidget">

        <pe:layoutPane position="west" resizeWhileDragging="true" closable="false" resizable="true"
            styleContent="overflow: auto;">

            <!-- canvas id="imagecanvasid" style="border: red solid; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;" /-->
            <div id="imageContainer" style="max-height: 100%;">
                <p:graphicImage id="imageid" value="#{myManagedBean.image}" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; position: absolute;" />
            </div>

            <pe:imageAreaSelect id="areaSelect" for="imageid" handles="false" show="false" hide="true"  
                autoHide="true" movable="false" persistent="false" resizable="false">  
                <p:ajax event="selectEnd" listener="#{myManagedBean.selectCoords}" />  
            </pe:imageAreaSelect>  

    </pe:layoutPane>
```

I cannot get the scaling of the overlays as divs working. I tried register a listener when the image size changes and resize the div, but there is a delay when the divs are getting updated.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Also made some tests with html5 canvas. Unfortunately the resizing and drawing is different on FF, Chrome and IE.

Comment: My use case: I want to draw an image resized with preserved ratio. I have to draw some stuff above the image (e. g. outline an area). These drawing must also scale when the image parent is resized.